# Passing data between Activities Android | java

Tags: android

Consider three Activities, A,B,C . I want to pass data from `Activity` A to `Activity` C, however `Activity` C is not launched from `Activity` A , instead it is launched from `Activity` B, So what I am looking for is a solution if I can send an `Integer` value to `Activity` C from `Activity` A , and `Activity` C receives that value whenever it gets executed, can I use `intent.putExtra()` for this purpose? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282288/pass-value-from-1st-activity-to-3rd-activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes You are right . you can use `intent.putExtra()`

1. You can do Pass data using `intent.putExtra()` from **activity A** to **activity B** .
2. Then sote that bundle in **activity B**
3. Then When you launching **Activty c** pass that bundle to intent
4. Catch that data in **activity c**

Comment: Thanks for answering that in a minimal way .

Comment: But again, the trouble is , Activity C is launched from a Broadcast receiver

Comment: but you mentioned `  instead it is launched from Activity B`

Comment: Yes, Its an alarm, From activity B  a Broadcast receiver is called, and at  a specific system time, Activity C is launched

Comment: so what you can do is `you can create serialize object write it to shared preference and access for there or put int into shared preference in and access that in activity c

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment so giving it as answer.
You answered in your question, intent.putExtra is the way to go. But pass the value from A to B and B to C, if you find it annoying make use of shared preferences and put value from activity A and when needed in activity C get the value and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep passing the bundle to activity B and get that data through intent and same thing you can pass that same bundle in activity B on click of a button or the selected view and get the same intent in Activity C, so finally your query has to be fulfill.

Answer (score 0):

if `intent.putExtra()` does not work for you then you can try saving data in application level.
You can save data from `A` to certain variable which is in Application level.
Or you can just use `sharedPreferences` or `sqlite`.