# How to pass data 1st activity to 2nd and 2nd activity to 3rd

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**NOTE:** I know how to pass data **Activity1** to **Activity2** Using Bundle and `PutExtra`.

I refer this below links :

- [How to pass data from 2nd activity to 1st activity when pressed back? - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [How to pass value from 1st activity to 3rd activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282288/how-to-pass-value-from-1st-activity-to-3rd-activity)

**QUESTION**

I've 3 activitys,  **Activity1**, **Activity2** and **Activity3**

In Activity 1 i have **data**. When i click on data **Activity2** is started.

In **Activity2** I've Textview. when i click on textView then open **Activity3**

In **Activity3** i have `EditText`

So i want to pass data **Activity1** *TO* **Activity2** *AND* **Activity2** *TO* **Activity3**

**Activity1** code:

```
private OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Base item) {
            Company company = (Company) item;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompanyDetailActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("company", company);
            //intent.putExtra("edit", "editFrag");
            intent.putExtra("company", item);
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.e("Item...","Item clicked "+company.getName());
        }
    };
```

**Activity2** code:

```
case R.id.rlCompanyProfile:
            //Base item = null;
            Company company = (Company) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("company") ;
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCompanyActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("company", company);
            //intent.putExtra("company", myData);
            intent.putExtra("edit", "editFrag");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
```

**Activity3** code:

```
Intent extras1 = getIntent();
        {


                        Company value = (Company) extras1.getSerializableExtra("company");
                        etCompanyName.setText(value.getName());
                        etWebsite.setText(value.getWebsite());
                        etEmail.setText(value.getEmail());
                        etPhoneHome.setText(value.getPhoneHome());
                        etPhonePrimary.setText(value.getPhonePrimary());
                        etAddressLine1.setText(value.getAddressLine1());
                        etAddressLine2.setText(value.getAddressLine2());
                        etCity.setText(value.getCity());
                        etZip.setText(value.getZipcode());
                    }
```

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: data can not pass activity1 **to** activity2 **and** activity2 **to** activity3 @PankajKumar

Comment: @MohammadAli share your code what did you tried so far?

Comment: wait for 2 mint @NileshRathod

Comment: can you tell me how it's duplicate @HemantParmar

Comment: @NileshRathod please check my code i'll paste

Comment: @MohammadAli what is `extras1` here

Comment: i'll already used `extras` for another in same activity so i can take `extras1` @NileshRathod

Comment: @MohammadAli  share the code of your Activity3  where your retrieving data

Comment: @MohammadAli first don't be too rude here. And if you are able to send data between A to B then there must be your code issue where you are not able to pass data between B to C.

Comment: @PankajKumar agree with u

Comment: May I know why your doing 'Base item = null;
Company company = (Company) item ;' these lines??? If you are sending null how you will get NOT NULL value?

Comment: i'll update my code @NileshRathod

Comment: Sorry for the rude behave @PankajKumar

Comment: Company is a Model class where i set getter and setter Method @PankajKumar

Comment: you better save that data in SharedPreference and then use it in any activity / fragment you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in Here Activity2 code check it

## You are passing `item = null`

Activity2 code:

```
case R.id.rlCompanyProfile:
Base item = null; // item object is null here
Company company = (Company) item ;// here you are passing null item object of your Company class
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCompanyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("company", item);
intent.putExtra("edit", "editFrag");
startActivity(intent);
break;
```

## EDIT

to send data to Activity use this

```
intent.putExtra("company", company);
```

To receive data in third activity use this

```
Company company=intent.getSerializableExtra("company");
```

Comment: Update your answer please... @NileshRathod

Comment: @MohammadAli done

Comment: ya good *AND* Thank you So much @NileshRathod

Comment: @MohammadAli welcome happy to help u

Answer (score 1):

You can use intent or bundle to pass the data.

You can also use shared preference to store and retrieve data. 
Use intent as below :

```
// send data
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("detailData",data);
    startActivity(intent);
//retrieve data
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String detailData = intent.getStringExtra("detailData");
```

Using bundle

```
 //Create the bundle 
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
bundle.putString("VENUE_NAME", venueName);
//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
//retrie bundle 
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
String venName = bundle.getString("VENUE_NAME");
```

Shared Prefrence :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("key", value);
                editor.commit();
//retrieve data
pref.getString("key", null); // getting String
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this nature using `startActivityForResult()` method of `Activity` class.

Refer this link [startActivityForResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android/10407371#10407371)

Answer (score 0):

Is not that hard, just use putExtra() in order to pass data between activities, the workflow will be this, first use putExtra() as your first intent to go to the second Activity, after your reach Activity 2, just get the results with the bundle getExtras() and after that just create another intent.putExtra() to send that data to Activity 3

The workflow should be like this

**Activity 1**

```
String myData = "StackOverflowRocks";

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("THE_ID_OF_WHAT_YOU_ARE_SENDING", myData);
startActivity(intent);
```

At **Activity 2** just get that data

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
 String getData;

if (extras != null) {
    userName = extras.getString("THE_ID_OF_WHAT_YOU_ARE_SENDING");
    // and get whatever type user account id is
}
```

Now that you have the data in Activity 2 , do the same thing as Activity 1 to Activity 2

```
String myData = getData;

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity3.class);
intent.putExtra("THE_ID_OF_WHAT_YOU_ARE_SENDING2", myData);
startActivity(intent);
```

And get it in your **Activity 3**

You can check your extras this way.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
 String getData;

if (extras != null) {
    userName = extras.getString("THE_ID_OF_WHAT_YOU_ARE_SENDING2");
    // and get whatever type user account id is
}
```

Edit: your problem is that you are sending data to your Activity 2 as item1 , but then in Activity 2 you are not getting that item1 data, you are just creating a new one and sending it to Activity 3.

Check this in your Activity 2

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCompanyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("company", item1);
intent.putExtra("edit", "editFrag");
```

Instead of creating a new item1, just get the data from the item1 from your activity 1:

```
String company = getIntent().getStringExtra("company");
```

Comment: it's say `getData` is null in  **Activity2**

Comment: added the check for null in the getExtra, if its showing null , maybe the variable type or the data you are passing is null, but this should work

Comment: i'll check in 1st activity data have in `item` but 2nd activity data can't catch

Comment: as im keep saying, you are getting wrong your item data buddy, post your POJO

Answer (score 0):

You can use sharedpreferance to store the data of **Activity1** and **Activity2** to pass in **Activity3**.