# Android - TextView setText updates text only sometimes

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm new to android development and I'm stuck with the following issue:

I have objects in a listView. When an item in the list is clicked a detailed page with the information appears. This worked fine until at some point the text was displayed only sometimes. When I go back and click on the very same item the text might get displayed correctly again (or not). I have done a textView.getText() and it displays the correct text in the logcat but the user can't actually see this text displayed in the app (at least not always). I wasn't able to pinpoint the mistake and I cannot reproduce the mistake regularly.

FYI: The genre gets displayed always. But title and author only sometimes.

I am grateful for any help! If you have any codestyle/bestpractice remarks please add those to your answers.

Below you can find the relevant code.

Best,
Marc

**Activity passing the data**

```
public class BooksActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final BooksDBOpenHelper dbHelper = new BooksDBOpenHelper(this, DBConstants.DB_NAME, null, 1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_books);

        TextView header = this.findViewById(R.id.tv_header);
        header.setText(R.string.books_list);

        ImageButton backButton = this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_back_button);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(view -> finish());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ArrayList<CustomBookItem> bookItems = new ArrayList<>();

        String table_name = DBConstants.Books.TABLE_NAME;
        String[] columns = {
                DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE,
                DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_AUTHOR,
                DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_GENRE,
                DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_ON_LOAN,
                DBConstants.ID
        };
        String where = null;
        String[] where_args = null;
        String group_by = null;
        String having = null;
        String order_by = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(table_name, columns, where, where_args, group_by, having, order_by);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            bookItems.add(new CustomBookItem(
                    cursor.getString(0),
                    cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3),
                    cursor.getString(4)
            ));
        }
        cursor.close();
        ListView lvMainList = findViewById(R.id.lv_books_list);
        CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, bookItems);
        lvMainList.setAdapter(customArrayAdapter);

        lvMainList.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, pos, id) -> {
            Log.i("BooksActivity", "item was clicked");
            CustomBookItem bookItem = (CustomBookItem) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, BookActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, bookItem.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra(DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_AUTHOR, bookItem.getAuthor());
            intent.putExtra(DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_GENRE, bookItem.getGenre());
            intent.putExtra(DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_ON_LOAN, bookItem.getOnLoan());
            intent.putExtra(DBConstants.ID, bookItem.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        });
        customArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

**Activity receiving the data**

```
public class BookActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Resources resources;
    private final BooksDBOpenHelper dbHelper = new BooksDBOpenHelper(this, DBConstants.DB_NAME, null, 1);
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);

        this.resources = this.getResources();

        TextView header = this.findViewById(R.id.tv_header);
        header.setText(R.string.book);

        ImageButton backButton = this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_back_button);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(view -> finish());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        String id = intent.getStringExtra(DBConstants.ID);

        TextView tvTitle = this.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
        tvTitle.setText(intent.getStringExtra(DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE));
        Log.d("BookActivity", tvTitle.getText().toString());
        TextView tvAuthor = this.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
        tvAuthor.setText(intent.getStringExtra(DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_AUTHOR));
        Log.d("BookActivity", tvAuthor.getText().toString());
        TextView tvGenre = this.findViewById(R.id.book_genre);
        tvGenre.setText(intent.getStringExtra(DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_GENRE));
        Log.d("BookActivity", tvGenre.getText().toString());

        View loanBookButton = this.findViewById(R.id.loanBookButton);
        View returnBookButton = this.findViewById(R.id.returnBookButton);

        if (intent.getStringExtra(DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_ON_LOAN).equals("0")) {
            returnBookButton.setBackgroundColor(this.resources.getColor(R.color.grayed_out));
            returnBookButton.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            loanBookButton.setBackgroundColor(this.resources.getColor(R.color.grayed_out));
            loanBookButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        loanBookButton.setOnClickListener(view -> loanBook(id));
        returnBookButton.setOnClickListener(view -> returnBook(id));

    }

    public void returnBook(String id) {
        this.db = this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        this.db.execSQL("UPDATE " + DBConstants.Books.TABLE_NAME +
                " SET " + DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_ON_LOAN + "='0' " +
                "WHERE id=" + id);

        this.finish();
    }

    public void loanBook(String id) {
        this.db = this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        this.db.execSQL("UPDATE " + DBConstants.Books.TABLE_NAME +
                " SET " + DBConstants.Books.COLUMN_NAME_ON_LOAN + "='1' " +
                "WHERE id=" + id);

        this.finish();
    }
}
```

**Layout of sending activity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/container_header_lyt"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_books_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/container_header_lyt"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout of receiving activity**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/container_header_lyt"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loanBookButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="580dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="229dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="103dp"
        android:text="@string/loan_book_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/returnBookButton"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="229dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="580dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="103dp"
        android:text="@string/return_book_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="174dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="176dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="487dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loanBookButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="176dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="399dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loanBookButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/book_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_genre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="176dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="311dp"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/loanBookButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/book_author" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit**

I restructured the layout of the receiving activity by changing it from a constraint layout to a relative. I don't know why this worked but it fixed my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application#:~:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20do,sessionId)%3B%20startActivity(intent)%3B

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432818/how-to-send-text-view-data-from-1st-activity-to-3rd-activity/55433201