# How to pass a variable from a activity to another, which is not the immediate activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

In android, to pass a variable from activity 1 to activity 2, intents are used. But how to pass variables from activity 1 to activity 3. In my project, I am getting a id from user in login activity, which is needed in other activity, but it is not the immediate activity to it. How to do this?

Comment: how you open from activity 1 to activity 3?

Comment: By going through the activity 2, but its little hard to pass from activity 1 to activity 2 and then to activity 3, how can I directly pass it?

Comment: how about this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12282529/5156075

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharedPreference

**Setting values in Preference:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "john");
 editor.putInt("id", 12);
 editor.apply();
```

**Retrieve data from preference:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString("name", "");
int idName = prefs.getInt("id", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a static variable in your Helper class,

```
public class Helper {
    public static int user_id;
}
```

Set its value in activity A:

```
    Helper.user_id = 309; // id you want to save.
```

And then access its value in Activity B:

```
    if(Helper.user_id != 0){
         user_id = Helper.user_id;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the id from one activity to another activity using the eventBus

**Gradle**

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
```

**Activity-1**: where you need to pass id

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

**Activity-3** : where you need to receive id

**Register eventBus**

```
@Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```

**Prepare subscribers**

Subscribers implement event handling methods (also called “subscriber methods”) that will be called when an event is posted. These are defined with the @Subscribe annotation.

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I will try it